# Минимум в скользящем окне

Tags: python

Нужно реализовать скользящий минимум. Для заданного массива чисел и числа K найти минимумы для всех отрезков длины K. Я решил сделать это с помощью обычных срезов, но вот скорость такого подхода - квадратичная, а нужна линейная.

```
n,k = map(int,input().split())
a = list(map(int,input().split()))

for i in range(n-k+1):
    print(min(a[i:-1]))
```

Как сделать умней?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/can-min-max-of-moving-window-achieve-in-on/12195098#12195098

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то скользящий минимум это не

```
min(a[i:-1])
```

а

```
min(a[i:i+k])
```

И соответственно скорость (конечно, не скорость, а сложность, ну да ладно) -

O(n*k) т.е. практически O(n)

Comment: `O(n*k)` - это `O(n*sqrt(n))`, а не `O(n)`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Даже для k=n/2 ?

Comment: @MBo, имелось в виду в худшем случае.

Comment: @Qwertiy Так вроде в худшем получается `O(n^2)`, а не `O(n^(3/2))`

Comment: А откуда появляется sqrt(n) или ^2 при фиксированном K?  И кстати, речь идет про "отрезков длины K".  У вас есть n внешних циклов "скольжения", в каждом - ищем минимум.  Поиск минимума в последовательности чисел - всегда требует ровно К операций. Откуда взялись корни и квадраты?

Comment: @MBo, нет, увеличивая длину окна ты уменьшаешь число окон. Например, если длина окна n-1, то таких окон всего 2. Максимум будет на квадратном корне. Хотя стоп...

Comment: @passant, лучше скажи, откуда взялось фиксированное k, если оно тоже входной параметр?

Comment: @MBo, ты прав - `O(n**2)`. Максимум на половине количества и получается число окон n/2, а размер окна n/2, а значит асимптотика квадратичная.